# Swift Create String By Adding Percents

Tags: swift, deprecated, urlencode, deprecation-warning

How would I convert this to current swift syntax. I am having a hard time.

```
extension String {
    var escaped: String {
        return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,self as CFString!,"[]." as CFString!,":/?&=;+!#$()@',*" as CFString!,CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) as String
    }
}
```

Comment: i think it s `"string".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)`

Comment: @CerlinBoss not .`urlFragmentAllowed` and neither of the predefined constants.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
var escaped: String {
   let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":/?&=;+!#$()@',*")
   return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)!
}
```